# Use VBA to Autofill x number of rows for Name1, then x number of rows for Name2, etc. for all names on a list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to dynamically autofill a column with multiple names based on different x values to determine the number of rows per name.

For example,

I want Name1 to fill the first 12 rows starting in cell B9.
Then I want Name2 to fill the next 10 rows starting in cell B21. The x values will change daily so they need to be dynamic. Today I might want Name1 to fill the first 12 rows, but tomorrow only the first 5. I want Name2 to start the row right under Name1 and that's the part I'm struggling with.

I have code working that will reference a cell where I enter my x value and it autofills the first name in the range correctly. So, using my above example, I would type 12 in my x value cell (I9 is what I'm using) and when I run the macro, it fills cells B9-B20 with the name in B9.

I'm struggling for the code to then move to the next name on the list. I would want the next name to start in B21 and fill the number of rows I enter in cell I9.

Current code:

```vb
Sub AutoFillNames()

 
    With ActiveSheet
       AutoFillRange .Range("B9"), Range("I9").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Since Range ("B9") is hardcoded, it only wants to make that the starting point. I want to make "B9" dynamic.

Goal: I enter a value in I9, run the macro, have it fill the first name for that many rows. After that, I will manually enter a new name in the cell under the prior name. From there, I will enter my new x value in I9, run the macro, and that new name will be listed in the same column for the number of rows as the x value I typed under the first name.

Answer (score 1):

If I9 will always have the number of repeats:

```
Sub AutoFillNames()
    Dim c As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set c = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)     'last cell in ColB
        c.Resize(.Range("I9").Value).Value = c.Value  'resize and fill
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found `Tim` posted an answer before me. We are using same apporach. The only difference is below code includes data validation for cell I9 to make sure it is a positive number.

```vb
Sub AutoFillNames()
    Dim iCnt
    With ActiveSheet
        Set c = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
        iCnt = .Range("I9").Value
        If c.Row > 8 And VBA.IsNumeric(iCnt) And Val(iCnt) > 0 Then
            c.AutoFill c.Resize(iCnt, 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```